# restlet restlet use api spark ext generate swagger exception

Tags: restlet

I'm useing restlet, version 2.3.12. when using Swagger2SpecificationRestlet to generate swagger document, it failed with exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.construct(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/ClassIntrospector$MixInResolver;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedClass;
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RepresentationCollector.addRepresentation(RepresentationCollector.java:124)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ResourceCollector.completeOperationOutput(ResourceCollector.java:345)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ResourceCollector.completeOperation(ResourceCollector.java:199)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ResourceCollector.collectResource(ResourceCollector.java:125)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RestletCollector.collectForFinder(RestletCollector.java:100)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RestletCollector.collect(RestletCollector.java:64)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RestletCollector.collectForRoute(RestletCollector.java:116)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RestletCollector.collectForRouter(RestletCollector.java:136)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.RestletCollector.collect(RestletCollector.java:55)
    at org.restlet.ext.apispark.internal.introspection.application.ApplicationIntrospector.getDefinition(ApplicationIntrospector.java:169)

I see the source code, it calls a non exist function, I tried fasterxml jackson version from 2.7 to 2.9.

Comment: I also have this problem, did you ever solve it?